# Cluster in WCS (issue:- ear file not generate when created & started cluster)

Tags: websphere, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, wcs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzsgR.png)Create cluster .
I have Two Machines machine_A and Machine_B
Machine_A have wcsProfile (instance) and solrprofile.
Machine_B have WASprofile created by pmt.sh script.
Machine_B have DMGR profile.
- I have Federated node of wcsProfile in DMGR.
- I have Federated node of WASprofile in DMGR.
Restart manager and start Nodes then start wcsProfile and WASprofile servers.
Then created cluster and add nodes of wcsProfile and WASprofile.
Then start cluster cluster has started successfully but ear file is not created in /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/WasSrv01/installedApps/demoNode01Cell/ 'directory'
while ear file is exist in wcsProfile profile in another machine_A
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/wcshop/installedApp[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj6Ng.png)s/WC_wcshop_cell/WC_wcshop.ear

problem 1:- ear file is not created in 
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/WasSrv01/installedApps/demoNode01Cell/
Problem 2:- cloneid is not exist in plugin-cfg.xml for both cluster member.

Comment: You should be able to see the outbound Set-Cookie first.

-1 is used by "base" non-clustered application standalone application servers. It could just be old.

Comment: Now i am getting only one cloneID in plugin file and matching cookies jsessionID . I added cloneID from ibm console Types server ->WebSphere application servers ->Application servers > wcs_server1 > Web container > Custom properties and Added  cloneID for all servers but only got one cloneid in plugin-cfg.xml of webserver  .

Comment: One cloneid, or one server, in plugin-cfg.xml? Are you using ND?

Comment: Hi covener, I have described all details in Question area so please see above question again because I have updated my issue.